# What does HostAuthenticationFilter do?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, owin

Can somone please explain what these two lines of code mean inside the Register() method of my WebApiConfig.cs file.

```
// Web API configuration and services
// Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));
```

I assume its adding HostAuthentication application wide. But even if I don't pass a bearer token with my requests I am still able to get the data.  So whats the point of adding this filter?

Answer (score 7):

I usually keep the following comments in my code as a reminder of what they are for.

```
// Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
// If you don't want the OWIN authentication to flow to your Web API then call 
// SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication on your HttpConfiguration. 
// This blocks all host level authentication at that point in the pipeline.
config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
//config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

// “Host-level authentication” is authentication performed by the host (such as IIS), 
// before the request reaches the Web API framework. 
// ----
// Often, you may want to to enable host-level authentication for the rest of your application, 
// but disable it for your Web API controllers. For example, a typical scenario is to 
// enable Forms Authentication at the host level, but use token-based authentication for Web API.
// ----
// To disable host-level authentication inside the Web API pipeline, call config.SuppressHostPrincipal() 
// in your configuration. This causes Web API to remove the IPrincipal from any request that enters 
// the Web API pipeline. Effectively, it "un-authenticates" the request.
config.SuppressHostPrincipal();
```

Also if you are still getting access to action data, chances are you did not apply `[Authorize]` attribute to the controller or action to restrict access.

Related reading [Host authentication and Web API with OWIN and active vs. passive authentication middleware](https://brockallen.com/2013/10/27/host-authentication-and-web-api-with-owin-and-active-vs-passive-authentication-middleware/)

Comment: So if i comment out both config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication(); and       config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType)); then that means even if I i have [Authorize] attribute applied to my controller or action, I should be able to access the data anyway since default authorization is suppressed and nothing new is added?..

Comment: @psj01 No that is different. The authorize attribute will check to make sure that a user is defined on the request. If not it will fail by default. That is by design. Even if you comment out what you stated.

Comment: If i add config.SuppressHostPrincipal(); then it shouldn't check to make sure that a user is defined?

Comment: NO it wont check IIS for the user. `To disable host-level authentication inside the Web API pipeline, call config.SuppressHostPrincipal() in your configuration. This causes Web API to remove the IPrincipal from any request that enters 
 the Web API pipeline. Effectively, it "un-authenticates" the request.`

Comment: You are confusing the purpose of the attribute and the pipeline